# How to keep external monitor as default montior when I disconnect the laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop that I dock to two larger external monitors when at home, and also carry with me often.

I use one of my external monitors as the primary monitor when at home.  However, whenever I disconnect the laptop to take with me it switches the default monitor to the laptops tiny monitor, forcing me to reconfigure the default monitor settings once I dock my laptop again at home.

I'd like to configure windows 10 so it knows if I have an external monitor connected it should use it as the default monitor, while obviously continuing to use the laptop monitor as the default monitor if no external is connected.  How can I make this configuration persist as I use the laptop both docked and undocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good question to which there is no answer
(if you use Windows extended desktop mode of course).

In some cases, forced saving Windows Desktop elements/settings might be the solution.
Try **[DesktopOK](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK)** tools. Many settings will help you to find the right option